# Coordinate loop in Processing

Tags: image, loops, coordinates, processing

I wanted to make an image and I figured this was the quickest way.  The idea is that there are rows with lines 5 pixels high, and every new row, the amount of pixels in between the lines are 1 pixel more than the previous row.  It's been a while since I have used java and this is so far what I came up with

```
size(800,800);

int z = 2;
int w = 5;
int max = 800;
for(int y = 0;y<max;y++){
  for(int x = 0;x<max;x=x+z){
    point(x,y);
    if(y%10 == 0)z++;
  }
}
```

This code is not quite giving me what I expected, and I can't figure out why.  any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel dumb.

```
size(800,800);

int z = 2;
int w = 5;
int max = 800;
for(int y = 0;y<max;y++){
  for(int x = 0;x<max;point(x,y)){
    x=x+z;
  }
  if(y%5 == 0)z++;
}
```

all I had to do was move the if statement out of the second loop.